# Between 2 date/times in PL/SQL not giving expected answers

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a query in PL/SQL on Oracle 10g that isn't behaving as I thought.  I'm 100% sure I am doing something silly so I'm sorry.. Here goes:

I have some data in a table that looks like this:

[image]

I then went to query but using the time element, like this:

```
select * from dw_time
where createdtime > to_date('2012/04/12 03:06:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

When this is executed we get records returned that include the rows in the image 03:05AM.  So thinking it was the to_date function I checked that:

```
select  to_date('2012/04/12 10:24:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss')
from dual;
```

[image: results]

Now I was totally confused as it clearly know that as a time.  So I tried it again:

```
select * from dw_time
where createdtime > to_date('2012/04/12 03:06:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

[image]

As you can see it is totally ignoring the time component! At this point I thought it was time to ask the gurus on here!

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: Is it possible that in your table '12/4/2012' means 4 Dec 2012 and query outputs it in MM/DD/YYYY format?

Comment: Hang on - you may be right there...

Comment: `select to_char(createdtime,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dw_time`

Comment: valex - I knew I was doing something daft! How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Ok I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that in your table '12/4/2012' means 4 Dec 2012 and query outputs it in MM/DD/YYYY format?

Answer (score 0):

Look at DB output date format - it's MM/DD/YYYY - you can see it on output of:

```
 select  to_date('2012/04/12 10:24:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss') from dual;
```

So change your select to:

```
select * from dw_time where createdtime > to_date('2012/12/04 03:06:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

You can see date output format by this query:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

And you can change date output format by this:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```